# Нахождение чисел на картинке

Tags: c#, изображения

Изображение на вход

[image: Изображение на вход]

На выходе должно получится так

[image: На выходе должно получится так]

---

Как это реализовать?Какие библиотеки стоит для этого использовать на c# ?

Comment: Найти какую-нибудь OCR библиотеку, которая распознает текст и выплевывает координаты и на основании этих координат рисует прямоугольники.

Comment: А ocr библиотеке обязательно распознавать весь текст?Можно ли распознать только числа?

Comment: Зависит от конкретной OCR.

Comment: Tesseract OCR от google подходит хорошо под эти цели,как набрасаю код выложу)Спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения даной задачи можно использовать [Tesseract .NET wrapper](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract). Он имеет более дружелюбный синтаксис, чем оригинальный Tesseract :

```
using (var engine = new TesseractEngine(pathToLangFolder, "eng", EngineMode.Default))
{
    // have to load Pix via a bitmap since Pix doesn't support loading a stream.
    using (var image = new Bitmap(fileName))
    {
        using (var pix = PixConverter.ToPix(image))
        {
            using (var page = engine.Process(pix))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(page.GetMeanConfidence() + " : " + page.GetText());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Если на всех картинках на входе числа находятся в одном и том же болке, советую обрезать числа именно до размеров этого блока что бы тесеракт не обрабатывал лишнюю инфу. Потом просто через REGEX оставляешь только числа.

Comment: Про  Tesseract .NET wrapper не знал,спасибо! Но насчет чисел вроде можно  оставить распознавать только числа даже если они в смеси с буквами,судя по(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944830/how-to-make-tesseract-to-recognize-only-numbers-when-they-are-mixed-with-letter)

Comment: Вполне возможно, я не работал с распознаванием текста. Просто что-то где-то слышал :) Обрезать изображения если это возможно все равно советую)